# Automysqlbackup empty folders

Tags: backup

I am trying to setup `automysqlback` to backup all my sql databases everyday and keep last 10 days of backups.

Here is my config: http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/17254947/

When i run "sudo automysqlbackup"

I get:

```
Invoking backup method.

Parsed config file "/etc/automysqlbackup/automysqlbackup.conf"
Checking for permissions to write to folders:

base folder /mnt ... exists ... ok.

backup folder /mnt/backup/ ... exists ... writable? yes. Proceeding.
```

and nothing happens. Folders are created at /mnt/backup but there are no databases.

Ubuntu server 14.04

Can someone help me fix this? Thank you!

Comment: Are the user name and password correctly configured?

Comment: Yes, they are. @Jos

Comment: What I find curious is that on my 16.04 server, version 2.6 is the only one available, whereas you run 3.0rc2. Also, my default configuration file looks totally different from yours. For instance, mine has no rotation options at all. How did you install `automysqlbackup`?

Comment: @Jos I installed it from their website: https://sourceforge.net/projects/automysqlbackup/

2.5 and 2.6 do have daily rotation.

Answer (score 0):

i think its because by default the root owns the files and has rights 0600

```
sudo nano /etc/default/automysqlbackup
```

> Backup directory location e.g /backups
>   Folders inside this one will be created (daily, weekly, etc.), and the
>   subfolders will be database names. Note that backups will be owned by
>   root, with Unix rights 0600.